# Menubar not showing correctly on zoom in/out

Tags: html, css

I have  a menubar with 6 items:

[image]

[image]

When I zoom in/out, the layout changes:

Why could this be happening?

CSS:

```
.menubar {
float:left;
width:920px;    
background:url(../images/nav-back.png) top left repeat-x;
height:52px;
    padding:9px 10px 8px 10px;
    margin-bottom:32px;
 }
.menubar ul {
   float:left;
   background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
   width:100%;
   display: block; 
}
.menubar li { float:left; background:url(../images/depth.gif) top right no-repeat;   }
.menubar li.last { background:none;  }
.menubar li.first a { padding:16px 42px 16px 43px; }
.menubar li.last a { padding: 16px 43px 16px 44px; }
.menubar li a { padding:16px 18px; display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the part of code is in `percents` and another part in fixed size. But as there is no code in your question, i cant say how to improve it.

Comment: this is my css for menubar
.menubar ul {
float:left; 
background:url(../images/nav-bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
width:100%;
display: block;
}
.menubar li {
float:left;
background:url(../images/depth.gif) top right no-repeat; 
}
.menubar li.last {
background:none; 
}
.menubar li.first a {
padding:16px 42px 16px 43px;
}
.menubar li.last a {
padding: 16px 43px 16px 44px;
}
.menubar li a {
padding:16px 18px;
display: block;
}

Comment: @user1376575 just make `.menubar` `width` fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

As @loler said this could happen with fixed size properties. Try to make all your size properties with em (or percent). That should fix your problems.
Em is a relative value depending on the font size of the browser.  So if you scroll in and out the site always looks the same.